# iOS: Xcode font size Vs Adobe XD font size

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, adobe, font-size

**Units of font size**: I'm searching answers for the following, please help me to find it.

**1. Which unit does Xcode use for font sizes? I mean, is it Pixels or Points or some other term?**

One of the members of my designed team pointed at a label in iOS app that I'm working on and asked what is the font size of that label. What should I say? 12Px or 12Pt or just 12 (Saying a number without unit may lead to confusion)

**2. Can we put the same Adobe XD font size for a UILabel in Xcode?**

I'm developing iOS application UI from the designs in Abode XD. **Which unit does Abode XD use for font sizes?** I have tried to put the same font size(80) in Xcode, but it has slight differences, attached a screenshot. Do we need a conversion here?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to [this forum thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2140211) Adobe XD uses pixels:

> XD currently uses a virtual pixel for most of its measurements (including font size), which should be the same unit of measure as a CSS pixel, or most measurements in iOS. It's roughly equal to 1 physical pixel on a 72 dpi monitor (and, incidentally, a point).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this calculation is completely correct or not but after using it, the text size looks almost the same to me.

I was reading [this](https://community.adobe.com/t5/adobe-xd/which-unit-does-adobe-xd-use-for-pixel-sizing/td-p/8228778) discussion forum and found one image related to various measurements of a font. The unit of those fonts was in **pt**.

[image: Adobe XD - font size]

Then, I came across this table provided by [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)
[image]

As you can see, px is 1/96th of 1 inch and pt is 1/72th of 1 inch. With this, we can form an equation like this -

[image]

Since we are provided **pt** value by Adobe XD, we can easily calculate the **px** value.

Maybe this can solve the issue of different font sizes. The one provided by Adobe XD is completely different from the one used in CSS.